# Cant render titles from Algolia in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, algolia

I cannot get titles on the cards to be shown. The search bar works as intended, but every card should have a title on top.

In my Algolia search index every object has a unique 'title' attribute which i have created. When i use the docs (from Algolias site) the titles display just fine - but i dont want the highlight attribute so thats what i am trying to remove.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connectInfiniteHits } from 'react-instantsearch-native';



const InfiniteHits = ({ hits, hasMore, refineNext }) => {
 return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={hits}
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={item => item.objectID}
        onEndReached={() => hasMore && refineNext()}
        renderItem={(({ item }, index) => (
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <View style={TextBoxes.scrollcontainer}>
            <View style={TextBoxes.boxes} key={index}>
              <Text key={index} style={TextBoxes.style} hit={item}>
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          </View>
        ))}
      />
    </View>
  )
};


export default connectInfiniteHits(InfiniteHits);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, to where my problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue! I forgot to insert {item.title} within the  element :)

Comment: Press the green check mark so the question is answered